# Waiting for the debugger to connect to Iphone ov port 10000 via usb - visual studio for mac maui

Tags: visual-studio, maui, visual-studio-mac

I am not very familiar with Mac as I do all my development in windows but I need to verify a functionality that only works on a mac and when running any project in mac I cannot connect to the debugger and getting

> "Waiting for the debugger to connect to Iphone over port 10000 via usb"

Can anyone suggest what it needs changing or settings etc..

- I have Xcode 14.3.1
- Visual Studio for mac 17.6.5 (runtime .net 7.0.3)

I am trying to test push notification using xamarin.firebase.cloudmessaging and sharedInstance is always null in windows, despite having below and that is why I am now trying to test using the mac

```
<ItemGroup>
    <BundleResource Include="Platforms\iOS\GoogleService-Info.plist" Link="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
</ItemGroup>
```

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you have updated Xcode (on your Mac) but the Visual Studio bits have not been updated to work with the new version of Xcode yet.

There are a couple of options:

1. Usually it works to launch the app manually and the rest should still mostly work unless some breaking change happened
2. Downgrade Xcode for the time being and/or [manage with Xcodes](https://youtu.be/Lpq3-5VdizA)
3. Wait for Visual Studio to update, which is usually not the best option since you're then stuck waiting until that happens

At this point in time a Visual Studio update has just been released which should work with Xcode 15, so just updating Visual Studio might be your answer.

Comment: Hi thank you so much I have added more info in question - tried manually but same issue - installed xcodes and when trying to install any version it says "unable to install xCode" - lack of familiarity with mac does not help at all ..